# Location of jar file inside lib directory

Tags: java, jar

My java project contains many jars for different purposes. e.g. spring framework jars, log4j, hibernate, etc.

My question is where should I place these jars in the lib folder?

1. Should I copy all these jars inside a single folder or
2. Create a different folder inside lib folder for each component, i.e. so my lib folder will have hibernate, spring, log4j folders inside it or
3. Create a folder structure similar to one created by Maven

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse IDE,use "User Libraries" tag to make different libraries.But all libraries put to WEB-INF/lib is also OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `Maven`, what I'd like to do is, to have each folder for each jar and create a subfolder for each version.

For example,

```
lib
|
---hibernate
      |+3.xx
          |+ .jar
---spring
      |+3.xx
          |+ .jar
```

But if you have only few jar files, you could put them all in one folder and your IDE will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

What is your deployment ? (WAR/EAR) ?. In either case, all the jars files go directly under lib folder